# Are there any vodka cocktail recipes for someone who likes whisky/scotch?

Tags: vodka, whiskey, scotch

I typically drink brown spirits, however, I have some vodka left over from a wedding party so I was wondering if there are any good vodka cocktail recipes which aren't too sweet (or have too many ingredients) and would be enjoyed by someone who has a pallet for whisky/scotch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are few cocktails that I can recommend and don't require much ingredients:

1) Black Russian - Vodka and coffee liqueur

2) Screwdriver - Vodka and orange juice

3) Greyhound - Vodka and grape juice

4) Vodka Martini - My favorite

Comment: I like the Black Russian recipe and shame on me for not thinking about the classic Vodka Martini.